# В чем может быть проблема при подключении к MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Создаю таблицу "`users`".

Затем прописываю в php файл:

```
mysql_connect ("localhost","radnk2xz_users","123456");
mysql_select_db ("users");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

В результате выдает ошибку, что таблица не выбрана.

Удаляю старую и создаю новую с названием "radnk2xz_users". Затем прописываю в php файл.

```
mysql_connect ("localhost","radnk2xz_users","123456");
mysql_select_db ("radnk2xz_users");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

И таким макаром все работает отлично, но вот так ведь по идее не должно быть. Должно все работать отлично и с первым вариантом? Cкажите, в чем моя ошибка, что я делаю не так?

За ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создали таблицу `users`? А в какой БД она находится? Разве в базе `users`? Че-то чувство такое, что в БД `radnk2xz_users`

Я так понял, что вы перепутали таблицу с БД, укажите в первом случае БД, в которой находится эта таблица - и работайте в SQL с этой таблицей.

**UPD:**

Т.е. если очень грубо:

```
$conn = mysql_connect ("localhost","radnk2xz_users","123456");
if ($conn) {
    $db = mysql_select_db ("radnk2xz_users");
    if ($db) {
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

        $sql = "...";//Например "SELECT COUNT(1) AS `cnt` FROM `users`";
        $result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);

        //Выполняем нужные действия
        //Например,
        //while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //Обрабатываем каждую строку таблицы
        //}
    } else {
        echo "Не удалось подключиться к выбранной БД";
    }
} else {
    echo "Подключение к MySQL было неуспешным";
}
```

Comment: radnk2xz_users, это мой логин.

вот как оно выходит: http://SSMaker.ru/399794b0/

не правильно ?

Comment: Так у вас же русским языком написано: БД radnk2xz_users, таблица users, т.е.  второй случай и работал:

    mysql_connect ("localhost","radnk2xz_users","123456");
    mysql_select_db ("radnk2xz_users");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

А дальше выполняете SQL, в котором можете обращаться к вашей таблице users, либо к любой другой, созданной в этой БД (radnk2xz_users)

Comment: Вы видно не совсем понимаете что происходит.

1) mysql_connect ("localhost","radnk2xz_users","123456");
Подключаемся к MySQL, находящейся на хосте "localhost", используя имя "radnk2xz_users" и пароль "123456".

2) Выбираем БД (не таблицу), с которой будем работать. У нас она - "radnk2xz_users"

3) Устанавливаем кодировку, в которой будем работать с данными.

Comment: BOPOH, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не использовать такие имена для DB, лучше придумайте название проекту и назавите так БД. Вполне может быть что это имя зарезервировано, однако могу ошибаться, в любом случае не проще создать БД с нормальным именем??

Comment: С нормальным именем это с каким ? 

пробовал по разному, работает только так )))

а что касается "radnk2xz_", так это требование хостинга http://SSMaker.ru/4d63089b/

или можно как то еще по другому делать ?

Comment: а не пробовали PDO использовать? синтаксис простой как и установка кодировки соединения + поддержка не закончится в ближайшее время